# How to get max count of foreign key SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

```
NoRoom varchar(50) primary key,
kindRoom nvarchar(50),
price float,
priceCurrent float,
R_status nvarchar(50),  

nametour nvarchar(50),
checkIn date,
checkOut date,
company nvarchar(50),
idRoom nvarchar(50) foreign key references Rooms(NoRoom)
```

and here is my code

```
SELECT rooms.noroom, 
       rooms.kindroom, 
       Count(checkintour.idroom) AS numberoforder 
FROM   rooms 
       LEFT JOIN checkintour 
              ON( rooms.noroom = checkintour.idroom ) 
GROUP  BY rooms.noroom, 
          rooms.kindroom 
ORDER  BY numberoforder DESC
```

output is like this

```
+-----------+----------+----------------+
|   No Room | KindRoom | NumberOfOrder  |
+-----------+----------+----------------+
|  PO0051     VIP               1 
|  PO0053     Single            1 
|  PO0054     VIP               1
|  PO0055     VIP               1 
|  PO0056     VIP               1 
|  PO0057     VIp               1
|  PO0058     VIP               1
|  PO0059     VIP               .
|  PO0060     .                 ..
|  PO0061     ..                ...
|  PO0062
|           |          |
|           |          |                |
|           |          |                |
+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

how can get max NumberOfOrder ?
other word, If type of room is VIP i want to Sum all numbersof Order of that Room

Comment: Can you add the expected output. Do you want to show the sum of `NumberOfOrder` for all the `No Room`

Comment: No I want here is to Count the Type of Room not just show them all, if it is single room i want to count how many orders are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT rooms.noroom, 
       rooms.kindroom, 
       Count(checkintour.idroom) AS numberoforder 
FROM   checkintour
       JOIN rooms  ON rooms.noroom = checkintour.idroom
GROUP  BY rooms.noroom, rooms.kindroom 
ORDER  BY checkintour.idroom DESC
```

Comment: Can you please post it as a comment or help on how it would fix issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it

```
select Rooms.kindRoom,
COUNT(CheckInTour.idRoom) as numberoforder
from Rooms
left join CheckInTour
on(Rooms.NoRoom = CheckInTour.idRoom)
group by
Rooms.kindRoom
order by numberoforder desc
```